# how check if a cell in a dataframe is a substring of another cell from a different column but the same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So basically i'm wondering whether what I'm trying to do is possible or are there any other methods to acheive the same thing?

This is the starting table

| Id | Name | smaller | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAMEBIG | BIG | ------- |
| 2 | ABCDE | AB | ------- |
| 3 | Two | Ti | ------- |
| 4 | Tiht | Tih | ------- |

I want to the result to be

| Id | Name | smaller | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAMEBIG | BIG | 1 |
| 2 | ABCDE | AB | 1 |
| 3 | Two | Ti | 0 |
| 4 | Tiht | Tih | 1 |

so like the value in result will be `1` if the cell in `smaller` is a substring of cell from `Name` or else `0`

I tried things like

```
new_df['Animation'] = new_df['Animation'].apply(lambda x: return if x in new_df['Genre'])
```

and

```
for each in list(gen):
   if each in new_df['Genre']:
       new_df[each] = 1
   else:
       new_df[each] = 0
new_df
```

and this

```
for each in list(gen):
    new_df.loc[each in new_df.Genre, each] = 1
new_df
```

All I get is syntax error, can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: Use `zip`: `df['result'] = [int(smaller in name) for smaller, name in zip(df.smaller, df.Name)]`

Comment: @Psidom I get a ```TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float```

Comment: You have some values as float. Convert them to str first: `zip(df.smaller.astype(str), df.Name.astype(str))`

Comment: @Psidom it works thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df["result"] = df.apply(lambda x: 1*(x["smaller"] in x["Name"]), axis=1)
>>> df
   id     Name smaller  result
0   1  NAMEBIG     BIG       1
1   2    ABCDE      AB       1
2   3      Two      Ti       0
3   4     Tiht     Tih       1
```